# Return all tags and values of a given object within xml document in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have xml which looks like this...

```
<CONFIG2>
    <OBJECT id="{2D3474AA-9A0F-4696-979C-1BCE9350F3BD}" type="3" name="Test2" rev="1">
        <RULEITEM>
            <ID>{BF7D00C5-57BC-4187-9B07-064BA5744A12}</ID>
            <PROPERTIES>
                <columnname/>
                <columnvalue/>
                <days>|</days>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <eventdate>0001-01-01</eventdate>
                <eventtime>00:00:00</eventtime>
                <function>average</function>
                <parameters/>
                <stattype>standard</stattype>
            </PROPERTIES>
            <ITEM>
                <ID>{61C82F62-8F31-4754-A705-7CCBB34C6FD4}</ID>
                <PROPERTIES>
                    <actionindex>0</actionindex>
                    <actiontype>eventlog</actiontype>
                    <severity>error</severity>
                </PROPERTIES>
            </ITEM>
        </RULEITEM>
        <PROPERTIES>
            <groups>|</groups>
        </PROPERTIES>
    </OBJECT>
```

I am trying to return everything within OBJECT and /OBJECT.

For example, I would like to return all tags and values for the OBJECT where type="3" and name="test2".

Here is my current python script...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\xml\config.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

objectType = input("What object type are you looking for?: ")

for item in root.findall('OBJECT'):
    if item.attrib['type'] == objectType:
        print(item.get('name'))

objectName = input("What is the name of the object you are looking for?: ")

for item in root.findall('OBJECT'):
    if item.attrib['type'] == objectType and item.get('name') == objectName:
        print(list(item))
```

This returns...

```
 <Element "RULEITEM' at 0x00064F3C0>, <Element 'PROPERTIES' at 0x0064FB40>
```

I like it to return the entire object and all tags and values. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adjusting second loop by using another `findall()` iteration on all of `OBJECT's` children and grandchildren and so forth using (`//*`). Also, consider appending to a pre-defined list instead of `list()` (which would have broken each character of the loops' text item) and condition it to remove `None` values (i.e., empty nodes). Finally, use the `tag` and `text` property of the node:

```
... same code as above...

values = []
for item in root.findall('OBJECT'):
    if item.attrib['type'] == objectType and item.get('name') == objectName:
        for data in root.findall("OBJECT//*"):
            if data.text is not None:
                values.append(data.tag + ': ' + data.text)

for v in values:
    print(v)

#What object type are you looking for?: 3
#Test2
#What is the name of the object you are looking for?: Test2
#RULEITEM: 
#            
#ID: {BF7D00C5-57BC-4187-9B07-064BA5744A12}
#PROPERTIES: 
#                
#days: |
#enabled: 1
#eventdate: 0001-01-01
#eventtime: 00:00:00
#function: average
#stattype: standard
#ITEM: 
#                
#ID: {61C82F62-8F31-4754-A705-7CCBB34C6FD4}
#PROPERTIES: 
#                    
#actionindex: 0
#actiontype: eventlog
#severity: error
#PROPERTIES: 
#            
#groups: |
```